# confidence interval of regression coefficients in `lmer`

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

`lmer` function of `lme4` package gives profile likelihood interval of nuisance parameters. For example,

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)

pp <- profile(fit,"theta_")#profiling of the deviance
ci <- confint(pp)
```

The function gives wald statistics of estimates by the following codes:

```
res <- summary(fit)
se <- coefficients(res)[,2]
```

Is it possible to get profile likelihood interval of  regression coefficient too?

Comment: Isn't confint(fm1) what you are asking for?

Comment: Package bbmle may have what you need. Check ?bbmle:profile-methods.

Comment: @Roland Thank you so much.

Comment: @Roland another question for understanding the output of `confint(fm1)`. Are those values confidence limits for standard deviation(.sig01,.sig02,sig03,.sigma) and regression coefficients(Intercept,Days)?

Comment: Have you read help("confint.merMod")?